# How to convert dash-case to camelCase in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Is there any utility function in AngularJS that converts a dash-case string to a camelCase string? e.g.: "min-max" becomes "minMax"

That's quite simple to implement my own function:

```
function toCamelCase(name) {
  return name.replace(/-(\w)/g, function(match) {
    return match[1].toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

But, I know that Angular already does this (e.g. directive name), so I wonder if it's possible to use the mechanism that Angular has?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In angular this is part of jqlite, the minimalistic jquery implementation that they're using internally. I don't think there's a way of accessing that because I believe it's private. This is the function though:

```
function camelCase(name) {
  return name.
    replace(SPECIAL_CHARS_REGEXP, function(_, separator, letter, offset) {
      return offset ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter;
    }).
    replace(MOZ_HACK_REGEXP, 'Moz$1');
}
```

Where

```
var SPECIAL_CHARS_REGEXP = /([\:\-\_]+(.))/g;
var MOZ_HACK_REGEXP = /^moz([A-Z])/;
```

Answer (score 50):

You can access to angular's camelCase function inside of a directive:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  attrs.$normalize('ng-model'); // ngModel
  attrs.$normalize('ng:click'); // ngClick
  attrs.$normalize('ng_show'); // ngShow
}
```

Best!

Comment: Sir, you are a true scholar and gentleman! Didn't know `$normalize` existed.

Comment: Anyone know the opposite of this? That is "ngModel" => "ng-model" other than `"ngModel".replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-$1').toLowerCase();`?

Comment: @Campbeln `$normalize` handles various input formats, but you can normalize into an arbitrary format doing something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ricksmt/egaewd1j/1/).

Comment: That code in simple is: `"camelCase".replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(c) { return '-' + c.toLowerCase(); });` and @ricksmt You should post that as a question and answer of it's own.